# why doesn't python rereference this existing object?

Tags: python

When I declare a variable in Python it references an object.  In this case my object is the string 'test'.  When I concatenate it with 'ing123', the variable a now points to a string object 'testing123'.  However the reference count for 'testing123' does not increase.  Why does this happen?  I thought that python would simply rereference the previously existing 'testing123' string object.  In this case it appears it's creating another object that getrefcount does not recognize.  I guess my question is....  why does this occur?  I was expecting the second call to getrefcount to return a 5 instead of a 4.

```
from sys import getrefcount

b = 'testing123'
print getrefcount('testing123')
a = 'test'
a += 'ing123'
print getrefcount('testing123')
print a
```

prints...

```
4
4
testing123
```

Comment: Why would the interpreter waste time trying to detect that a *computed* string already exists?

Comment: c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611750/under-which-circumstances-do-equal-strings-share-the-same-reference

Comment: @CristianCiupitu  I don't know.  That's why I asked.  If you could elaborate on your comment, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: @Dave  Thanks for the link.  The top answer there seems to chalk it up to "The details of when strings are cached and reused are implementation-dependent, can change from Python version to Python version and cannot be relied upon"  So it seems that an existing object is not always referenced.

Comment: @nater: there isn't much to elaborate, I was only trying to emphasize a possible reason for which that doesn't happen.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu  I think I see what you mean though.  JanneKarila posted a link to an answer that expands on what you were saying.  It boils down to not wasting time looking for existing objects because it will effect runtime speed, right?

Comment: Yes, that's how I see it, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`intern`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern) the strings to get the behavior you want:

```
>>> b = intern('testing123')
>>> getrefcount(b)
2
>>> a = 'test'
>>> a = intern(a+'ing123')
>>> getrefcount(b)
3
>>> a is b
True
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question ("Why does python do this"), but useful nonetheless. +1

Comment: Here some thoughts on the why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2124011/222914

Comment: @JanneKarila  Thanks for the link.  That is a very good explanation of why this is happening.  I think this is what CristianCiupitu was talking about, if python tried to lookup a computed string in the memory each time, runtime speed would suffer.

Comment: The link you posted answers my question so I'll give you the correct answer.

Answer (score -4):

This is not recommended to do this.

Use dictionary for this, it´s more securely.

Try this

```
dict = { 'testing123' : 4 }
a = 'test'
a += 'ing123'
print dict[a]
```

Comment: You missed the point of this question; plus, redefining `dict` is not recommended.