# Python: Literals: Evaluation of Literals

Tags: python, literals, evaluation

From the Python documentation:

> [6.2.2. Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#literals)
> ...
> Multiple evaluations of literals with the same value (either the same occurrence in the program text or a different occurrence) may obtain *the same object or a different object* with the same value.

I need to understand this passage above but find it uneasy. I need your help to clarify certain things:

```
>>> " Got any rivers you think are uncrossable ?" #1
' Got any rivers you think are uncrossable ?' #2
>>> " Got any rivers you think are uncrossable ?" #3
' Got any rivers you think are uncrossable ?' #4
```

#1 and #3 are two literals with the same value that obtain the same objects #2 and #4 respectively. The value of these objects is the same.
How could their evaluation obtain different objects with the same value?
What has occurrence to do with the result of evaluation here?

> either the same occurrence in the program text or a different
> occurrence

How to distinguish between the same occurrence and a different occurrence ?
And what has the place of occurrence to do with the result of evaluation ?

Comment: You can imagine WHY this might happen.  It makes sense to consolidate small strings, but with a large string, it might be cheaper to create a new object than to scan through the set of existing string literals looking for a match.  As I said, it would be irrelevant to your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Why does ("hello" is "hello") evaluate as True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392433/python-why-does-hello-is-hello-evaluate-as-true)

Comment: See [Under which circumstances do equal strings share the same reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11611750/3890632)

Answer (score 2):

Both are string objects and have different ids even if the value is the same. E.g.:

```py
>>> id("My string")
140140708077104
>>> id("My string")
140140708085936
>>> my_first_string = "Repeated value"
>>> my_second_string = "Repeated value"
>>> my_first_string == my_second_string
True
>>> id(my_first_string) == id(my_second_string)
False
```

Comment: That's in an interactive session. Try it inside a script and see if you get the same result.

Comment: This is called string pooling or string interning. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1392927/9224678) question/answer for some good discussion

Comment: Totally right!! Thanks for the link with the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Compare these two:

```py
>>> a = 'a'
>>> b = 'a'
>>> id(a)
1799740566768
>>> id(b)
1799740566768
```

vs

```
>>> a = 'a b'
>>> b = 'a b'
>>> id(a)
1799740710960
>>> id(b)
1799751802672
```

Internally, in the first example, `a` and `b` both refer to the *same* object, while in the second, they refer to *different* objects.

This can have some unexpected results: in the first case, `a is b -> True` but in the second, `a is b -> False`.

#### Why does it matter?

As remarked in a comment, you likely shouldn't need to care.  In the case of  *immutable* literals, it should make no difference functionally whether your code refers to the same object, or different objects, when accessing 'identical' literals. But, in the case of **mutable** objects, it is definitely important to be aware of possible side-effects.

For more info, see e.g.
[Under which circumstances do equal strings share the same reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611750/under-which-circumstances-do-equal-strings-share-the-same-reference) and [What does sys.intern() do and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136826/what-does-sys-intern-do-and-when-should-it-be-used)

*Edit*: test results if you get the same object or different objects, using the below script:

```py
if __name__=="__main__":
    for i in range(100):
        a = ''.join(['a']*i)
        b = ''.join(['a']*i)
        print(f'a: {a}\nb: {b}\na is b: {a is b}')
```

gives me the following results, running Python 3.9.7 in Windows PowerShell:

```py
a:
b:
a is b: True
a: a
b: a
a is b: True
a: aa
b: aa
a is b: False
a: aaa
b: aaa
a is b: False
a: aaaa
b: aaaa
a is b: False
a: aaaaa
b: aaaaa
a is b: False
a: aaaaaa
b: aaaaaa
a is b: False
... etc.
```

Comment: Though the strings are separate objects inside an interactive session, that is not the typical behaviour when two identical string literals occur inside the same script.

Comment: @khelwood source?

Comment: "if the same string literal occurs twice in the source code, they will end up pointing to the same string object" in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11611774/3890632) to the first question you linked. Also, just try it.

Comment: To follow up on the claim, in trying for myself, I'm not able to replicate 'same string literal pointing to same string object' using the test script in the question edit.

Comment: Your test is not testing the same thing: they're not string literals.

Comment: In the first question I linked, I see "The details of when strings are cached and reused are implementation-dependent, can change from Python version to Python version and cannot be relied upon." -- i.e. results may vary, no?

Comment: Hence my saying "the *typical* behaviour".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238414/discussion-between-joshua-voskamp-and-khelwood).

Answer (score 1):

The passage is referring to object *identity* vs. object *value*. The keyword `is` is used to compare to objects to be the *same* object; whereas the operator `==` is used to test for *equality*.

Two object instances can have the same value but be different objects.

Example for CPython, which caches certain integers as an internal optimization, **but it is not guaranteed**, so your result could be different:

```py
>>> a = 999
>>> b = 999
>>> a == b       # equal
True
>>> a is b       # not the same object!
False
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 5
>>> a == b       # also equal
True
>>> a is b       # and happen to be the same object
True
```

This demonstrates the phrase "may obtain the same object or a different object with the same value."